Прикрепить файл к записи strapi aiohttp
Всем привет. Столкнулся со следующими проблемами:

при загрузке файла в strapi изображение загружается в библиотеку, но поле media остаётся пустым
при передаче в refId int получаю ошибку:


TypeError: Can not serialize value type: <class 'int'>.

Вот код, которым я отправляю запрос к api:
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(json_serialize=ujson.dumps) as session:
        url = f"{STRAPI_BASE_URL}/upload"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {STRAPI_TOKEN}"
        }
        data = aiohttp.FormData()
        data.add_field("ref", "api::executor-new.executor-new")
        data.add_field("refId", "29")
        data.add_field("field", "portfolio")
        data.add_field("files",
                       image.getvalue(),
                       filename=str(user_id) + "dddddd",
                       content_type="image/png")
        async with session.post(url, headers=headers, data=data,
                                ) as response:

Причём если отправлять подобный запрос из postman или с помощью requests, то изображение прикрепляется к записи. В чём может быть проблема?

